# Server using a table that I didn't even mention in my code

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im using NetBeans 8.0 . I've created a table "full" in database "face" . Earlier , I created a table "student" in database "rishi" . Now , after deleting the table from database "rishi" & also after changing the database to "full" , I get the following error :-

> java.sql.SQLException: Base table or view not found message from server: "Table 'face.student' doesn't exist".

Here's my HTML code :-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Login !</h1>
        <hr>
        <form action = "Check" method = "post">
            <pre>
                Enter email :     <input type = "text" name = "email">
                Enter password :  <input type = "password" name = "pass">
                <input type = "submit" value = "Login">
            </pre>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <h3>New ? Sign in today !</h3>
        <form action = "New" method = "post">
            <pre>
                Enter name :        <input type = "text" name = "user">
                Enter email :       <input type = "text" name = "newEmail">
                Enter password :    <input type="password" name = "newPass">
                Re-enter password : <input type="password" name = "repass">
                                    <input type = "submit" value = "Sign Up">
            </pre>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my Servlet :-

```
public class New extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name = request.getParameter("user");
        String email = request.getParameter("newEmail");
        String pass = request.getParameter("newPass");
        String repass = request.getParameter("repass");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/face" , "root" , "root");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("select * from full");
            int flag = 0;

        while(r.next()) {
            String s = r.getString(2);
            if(pass.equals(repass) || email.equals(s)) {
                flag = 1;
            }
            else {
                flag = 2;
            }

            if(flag == 2) {
                response.sendRedirect("fail2.html");
            }
            else {
                String qr = String.format("insert into student values('%s','%s','%s')" , name , email , pass);
                st.executeUpdate(qr);
                response.sendRedirect("home.html");
            }
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            out.println("Cannot load driver !");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            out.println(ex);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       doGet(request,response);
    } 
}
```

What could possibly be going wrong ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Check out the answer you should find your problem here

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my bad - just re-read the question.. in fact your database connection is fine, because you still have database `face`

The problem is with your Insert statement - You are trying to insert data into a table which is non existent in the database.

```
String qr = String.format("insert into student values('%s','%s','%s')" , name , email , pass);
```

this is where the problem lies - so either you have to make a table `student` in that "new" database, OR change this to something existing in db.

```
String qr = String.format("insert into " insert valid table name here "values('%s','%s','%s')" , name , email , pass);
```

But i want to address different issue - I do not understand why you have this ?

```
if(pass.equals(repass) || email.equals(s)) {
    flag = 1;
}
else {
    flag = 2;
}
if(flag == 2) {
    response.sendRedirect("fail2.html");
}
else {
    String qr = String.format("insert into student values('%s','%s','%s')" , name , email , pass);
    st.executeUpdate(qr);
    response.sendRedirect("home.html");
}
```

this block seems to be (to me) redundat because you check if credentials mach if they do you set flag to 1 - so far so good, but if they don't you set flag to 2. Thats also fine - but why do you have ANOTHER if statement to check if the flag is 2 ? and if is you redirect to fail.html. Otherwise you do some query... Its kind of redundand ( unless you expect more than 2 flags) if you DONT then this block below is a lot nicer solution

```
if(pass.equals(repass) || email.equals(s)) {
    String qr = String.format("insert into student values('%s','%s','%s')" , name , email , pass);
    st.executeUpdate(qr);
    response.sendRedirect("home.html");
}
else {
    response.sendRedirect("fail2.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Err:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/face" , "root" , "root");
```

So, you're connecting to the `face` database.

And then

```
insert into student values('%s','%s','%s')
```

So, yes, your code tries to access the `face.student` table.